# crystal reports : parameter field not showing in select wizard

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report written in 10 with two parameter fields

start_date 
end_date

Both have been placed in the header of the report.  Now I would like to select the results of the report based on the 2 dates.  When I click on Select Wizard >> click "new" tab >> select database date type field and then "is between" condition.  The two parameter fields don't show up.

am i missing something?  why aren't the 2 parameter fields start_date and end_date showing up?

thanks in advance

Comment: I rarely use that interface, clicking the button to edit in the editor window instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that they parameter fields are of the same type as the field the you are comparing them to.

Also, as OMG Ponies suggested, I'd recommend typing out the formula in the editor of the Selection Expert. Hope this helps.